# Setting a button icon in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, icons, windows-phone-8.1

[image]

Is it possible the change the Icon for btnEdit in my C# code? For example, when you click on btnEdit, the Icon will switch from "Edit" to "Cancel"?

This app is for Windows Phone 8.1, and I want to use the icons that have already been provided.

I have so far been able to switch the label (btnEdit.Label = "Cancel") and this works, but I can't seem to get it working for Icon.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the icon to a Symbol Icon object and not a string

```
btnEdit.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Cancel);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// Use system provided icon
AppBarButton.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Cancel);

// Use custom font icon
AppBarButton.Icon = new FontIcon()
{
    FontFamily = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.FontFamily("Your font"),
    Glyph = "glype"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Create two buttons each for Edit and Cancel. Keep the Edit button visible ad Cancel button hidden.

```
Edit.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
Cancel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

When you click on Edit button reverse the visibility of buttons.

```
Edit.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
Cancel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

You can assign different icons for each buttons and manage them.